# JPA Hibernate could not extract ResultSet

Tags: hibernate, jpa

when I run this query:

```
String queryF = "SELECT c FROM CatRoles c WHERE c.rol IN :roles OR :roles IS NULL)";
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery(queryF);
    List<String> lstRoles = Arrays.asList("EMPLEADO","ADMINISTRADOR");
    q.setParameter("roles", lstRoles);
    List<CatRoles> actual = q.getResultList();
```

throws me the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:135) [hibernate-core-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar:4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1]

but when I run the query in Oracle SQL developer works well, the goal of query is that when I send a list of roles are deployed only those who want to send null as the complete catalog is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the query to be:

```
... OR c.rol is NULL
```

instead of

```
... or :roles is NULL
```